# how to split Django urls.py into multiple files

Tags: python, django

I have a function based view in my app, and I am trying to split my urls.py as follows

```
my_project/
  |- my_project/
    |- urls.py
  |- my_app/
    |- urls
      |- __init__.py
      |- dogs.py
      |- cats.py
    |- views
      |- __init__.py
      |- dogs
        |- index.py
...
```

```
# my_project/my_app/urls/__init__.py

from .dogs import urlpatterns as dog_urls
from .cats import urlpatterns as cat_urls

app_name = "pets"

urlpatterns = dog_urls + cat_urls
```

```
# my_project/my_app/urls/dogs.py

from .. import views

urlpatterns = [
  path("dogs/", views.dogs.index, name="dogs")
  ...
]
```

```
# my_project/my_project/urls.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path("pets/", include("pets.urls")),
  ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

With this set up I am getting this error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'pets.urls' (namespace)>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

I do not see where in my code I am creating a circular dependency, nor do I understand what I am doing wrong with urlpatterns.

Comment: How is it included in your core apps urls.py?

Comment: @liam I have added my core apps urls.py inside my question

Comment: I have tried to recreate the error but have been unsuccessful, if it is a circular import error due to your unique file structure, you may want to try absolute imports rather then relative ones

Comment: Oh and also idk if you just forgot it but you need to add the namespace parameter in the include() function in your core apss urls

`path("pets/", include("pets.urls", namespace="pets"))`

Comment: Thank you liam for pointing out my file structure. I realized that I had `__init__,py` instead of `__init__.py`